# Constantly update data from a server and print to a text box

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So, I have a server completely written in Python 2.7:

```
from socket import *
from select import *

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1993

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)    
server.bind((HOST, PORT))  
server.listen(5)    
clients = []

def getClients():
    to_use = []
    for client in clients:
        to_use.append(client[0])
    return to_use

while(True):
    read, write, error = select([server],[],[],0)

    if(len(read)):
        client, address = server.accept()
        clients.append([client, address, []])

    to_use = getClients()

    try:
        read, write,error = select(to_use,[],[],0)
        if(len(read)):
            for client in read:
                data = client.recv(1024)
                print(bytes.decode(data))
                if(data == 0):
                    for c in clients:
                        if c[0] == client:
                            clients.remove(c)
                            break
                else:
                    for c in clients:
                        c[2].append(data)

    except:
        pass

    try:
        to_use = getClients()
        read, write, error = select([], to_use, [], 0)

        if(len(write)):
            for client in write:
                for c in clients:
                    if c[0] == client:
                        for data in c[2]:
                            sent = client.send(data)
                            if(sent == len(data)):
                               c[2].remove(data)
                        break
    except:
        pass
```

> What I need to do is get constant updates for data (messages) from the
>   server and print them to a text box made in Tkinter.

The receiving code:

```
from socket import *
from select import *

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1993

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    data = bytes.decode(sock.recv(1024))
    print data
```

It doesn't have to be Tkinter, but that's what I have been trying in; as long as it uses a GUI. Don't worry about sending messages I just need to be able to receive the data and print it to the text box/area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to submit a comment first, but give this a try:

You can use something other than a start button to get things going I just put it there for ease of use

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading
from socket import *
from select import *

    master = Tk() #create the GUI window

    #put the test program in a seperate thread so it doesn't lock up the GUI
    def test_program_thread():
        thread = threading.Thread(None, test_program, None, (), {})
        thread.start()


    def test_program():
        HOST = "127.0.0.1"
        PORT = 1993

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

        while True:
            data = bytes.decode(sock.recv(1024))
            terminal_listbox.insert(END, str(data))
            master.update() #I don't think this line is necessary, but put it here just in case


    # set the gui window dimensions and the title on the GUI
    master.minsize(width=450, height=450)
    master.wm_title("Stack Problem")

    # Start button is set to y and starts the test program when hit
    start_button = Button(master, text='START', command=test_program_thread)
    start_button.place(x=5, y=5)

    # scroll bar for the terminal outputs
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
    scrollbar.place(x=420, y=150)

    # Terminal output. Auto scrolls to the bottom but also has the scroll bar incase you want to go back up
    terminal_listbox = Listbox(master, width=65, height=13)
    terminal_listbox.place(x=5, y=100)
    terminal_listbox.see(END)
    scrollbar.config(command=terminal_listbox.yview)

    #GUI loops here
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: In this specific case, calling `update` is very necessary. Without it, tkinter cannot process events. If it can't process events (including events that trigger a refresh of the window), it can't show the data.

Answer (score 3):

The basic framework is to first create all of the widgets. Next, write a function that reads the data and updates the UI. Finally, arrange to have this function called every few milliseconds.

Roughly speaking, it looks something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.text = tk.Text(root)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        ...

    def start(self):
        self.read_periodically()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def read_periodically(self):
        # read the data
        data = bytes.decode(sock.recv(1024))

        # update the UI
        self.text.insert("end", data)

        # cause this function to be called again in 100ms
        self.after(100, self.read_periodically)


example = Example()
example.start()
```

If the data is not a steady stream which causes `sock.recv(1024)` to block, your UI will freeze while it's waiting for data. If that's the case, you can move the reading of the socket to a thread, and have the thread communicate with the GUI via a thread-safe queue.

If the data is in a steady stream, or you set up a non-blocking socket, you don't have to do any of that.

Comment: Up 1 for thread-safe queue and Tkinter GUI updating. Best way to go.